Why does sodium ethoxide solution in ethanol not self-E2?
If E2 reactions are favored by primary alcohols and strongly basic conditions, why does sodium ethoxide solution in ethanol not E2 itself to form ethylene?

OH- is a poor leaving leaving group and the methyl group protons are not in the least bit acidic
